# get post thumbnail wp_list_pluck

Tags: wordpress

I wrote an ajax suggest plugin, and now I want to get the post thumbnail instead of the `post_title`, but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
$s = trim( stripslashes( $_GET['q'] ) );

$query_args = apply_filters( 'wpss_search_query_args', array(
    's'           => $s,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
), $s );

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->posts ) {
    $results = apply_filters( 'wpss_search_results', wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'post_title' ), $query );
    echo join( $results, "\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to get post thumbnails because the thumbnail is not a property of the [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object.

You can iterate over the posts and fetch the thumbnail by the post ID:

```
foreach($query->posts as $post) {
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
}
```